Using lambdas and templates with macros in C++
I'm wrapping a collection of boiler plated Async code snippets to learn more about macros & templating in Unreal Engine 5.3, C++ 17. Unfortunately my C++ capabilities are quite limited and just don't understand enough about the complexities of using templates and macros together. (The below example is only a 1 liner, but for more complex implementations should I even be using macros..?)
From what I can see i would only need to include the type declaration when calling the BlockingTask method but don't know how to pass that information through a macro.
How should I handle the macro/template syntax in order to fix the erroring lambda version?
Other.cpp
void TestSyntax(){
    
    //Preferred syntax, Argument Error: lambda[]() -> FString
    //No instance of function template "Async::BlockingTask" matches the argument list argument types are: (lambda[]()->FString)
    FString strA1 = ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_A([&]() { return Async_TestB(); });
    FString strA2 = ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_B([&]() { return Async_TestB(); });


    /* The rest all Work */

    //Verifying the template works when passing the type
    FString strB = ::Async::BlockingTask<FString>([&]() { return Async_TestB(); });

    //The macro works when passing the method as a variable.
    //I'd prefer to not have to manually declare the task though.
    TFunction<FString()> task_B = [this]() { return this->Async_TestB(); };
    FString strC = ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_B(task_B);
    FString strD = ::Async::BlockingTask(task_B);

}

Macros.h
#define ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_A(method) \
{ \
    ::Async::BlockingTask(method); \
}
#define ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_B(method) \
    ::Async::BlockingTask(method); \

namespace Async{

    template<typename T>
    T BlockingTask(TFunction<T()> method) {
        TFuture<T> result = AsyncThread(method);
        return result.Get();
    }
}

Please ignore the terrible concept of a task that blocks the calling thread. I started by templating the most basic implementation to reduce complexity while learning. I have 'good' implementations that support cancellation tokens and completion callbacks that i plan to create templated macros for once I understand how to do it correctly.
Edit1:
I didn't include the actual error text... my apologies, added now as comment above erroring line.
I've learnt that the {}'s in the ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_A macro aren't part of the syntax and were my misunderstanding of the reference I was using to learn. However ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_B without the extra {}'s suffers from the same error with my use of the lambdas.

"Using lambdas and templates with macros..." Don't, just don't. It would complicate things a lot. Macros should be avoided especially with modern c++. But if you're doing this as an exercise to learn more about macros, then that is completely okay/fine as code involving macros does show up in real codebase etc.

what is the gain of writing a macro here? I see only downsides but no up. Dont write a macro just because you can, rather avoid to write one whenever you can

Your failing syntax expands to FString strB = { ::Async::BlockingTask([&]() { return Async_TestB(); }) }; What are the extra {} for?

Macros should [almost] never by used in modern C++, and your case does not seems to be a good exception.

These example macros are effectively pointless as they're just one line static calls. (The simplest examples that cause the errors for me to learn/debug.) The code that caused the errors to appear is intended to learn both macro syntax/use and template syntax/use while determining which to use when and where. There are instances that I hadn't yet gotten to that have more than the single line in the macro but i encountered the lambda issue before getting there. (Honestly to me macros seem like a workaround for people who don't like static methods..)

@Caleth my impression was that the macros contents needed to be wrapped in braces. Is this just not true? I did find it odd, but don't know C++ nearly well enough.

Keep the templates, keep the lambdas, ditch the macros.

Macros do textual substitution. ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_A can't be used as an initialiser. ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_B is the same number of characters as ::Async::BlockingTask. Just use the latter

if you are writing macros you need to find the option of you compiler that shows you the output after preprocessing. For gcc it is -E. Looking only at the error of code that you cannot see (because it is only generated as part of compilation) can be too confusing. Sometimes the error message is clear enugh but not always.

and please include a [mcve] together with the error message in the question.

please do not alter the question to ask for something else after you received an answer. If you write "I know [what the answer explains]" in your question then its confusing for future readers. Its difficult to write good questions (more than answers) but keep in mind that this isnt a forum with the typical back and forth disucssion, its rather "a question, an answer" and thats it. And you can ask follow up quesitons, or ask for clarification by commenting on the answer.

So, when you run into a problem combining two things A and B, first step back and try to reproduce the problem using only A or B.  If you did this, you'll notice your macro has nothing to do with your problem.  Then you can focus on your real problem.  Someone found a problem in your macro and has pointed it out.  But your underlying problem wasn't fixed, because your macro problem was noise.  Go off and remove the macros from your problem and ask a new question: the code without the macros still won't work, and the macros won't get in the way of answers.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai not changing the question, just adding the error text as i forgot to paste it (as requested). While simultaneously clearing up a misunderstanding of mine about the {}'s included in the _A macro. My question about the use of generic lambdas in macro's which wrap a template function still stands. I don't know how to pass the function reference through in a generic manner. A 'fake' syntax like MY_MACRO<typename T>(argument) would address the issue, however it looks like macros should reaher be obsoleted in favor of templated static functions. (based on comments)

your comparison of macros with static functions is somewhat off. Generally those are orthogonal features. Macros are a way to generate code, this can be useful sometimes and sometimes it is merely obfuscation. This case is clearly the latter. Sorry for picking on it, but part of learning is learning when to use and when not to use it. Replacing some foo(x) with bar(x) is making the code less clear and achieves nothing. If you want to call foo(x) then your code should say foo(x) not something else

In C++ scopes are not expressions and therefore do not evaluate to a value, so this:
FString strA = ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_A([&]() { return Async_TestB(); });

which expands to this:
FString strA = { // <--- !
    ::Async::BlockingTask([&]() { return Async_TestB(); });
}; // <--- !

is no valid syntax. If you absolutely insist on wrapping everything in a lambda call for whatever reason, it would be this:
#define ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_C(method) \
[&]{ \
    return ::Async::BlockingTask(method); \
}()

Why that would be useful, I don't know.

I've learnt that the {}'s in the ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_A macro aren't part of the syntax and were my misunderstanding of the reference I was using to learn. (It still compiled oddly but would likely result in undesired behavior at runtime. ASYNC_BLOCKING_TASK_B without the extra {}'s suffers from the same error with my use of the lambdas. I'm not personally fond of lambda usage, I find them more difficult to read and seldom use them in C# preferring the use of function delegates. UE seems to want them a whole lot and I'm trying to not fight 'the unreal engine way' so I'm adapting.
